# Application Scope issue calling a subroutine

Tags: applescript

I have a short subroutine as follows:

```
on show_Dialog(msg)
  tell application "Script Debugger Demo"
    display dialog msg
  end tell
end show_Dialog
```

If I call it from a script with no tell statement owning it eg:

```
show_Dialog("well this works")
```

No probs. If I call it from within a code block that is a call to another application I get a (unspecified) error (-1708) eg:

```
tell application Mail
  show_Dialog("this will not work for sure")
end tell
```

Yet in side a script block I can put a tell application "Excel" command inside a tell application "Mail" code block.

How can I have a universal dialog subroutine that will always produce the dialog in a specific application? The problem is I have my apps assigned to different spaces and it's a pain when it jumps away from script debugger. There are many (OS X Spaces and/or Script Debugger) workarounds but I want to know why this code fails and how to execute it correctly.

Edit-> Even when I remove the 'tell application…' and 'end tell' lines from subroutine I get an error.

Answer (score 5):

The error happens because your current target is application Mail. That means that everything is targeted towards mail. Mail doesn't know the handler show_Dialog() and returns an error. To set the target back to your current script you can add the word *my* in front of the handler call, add *of me* to the end of the handler call or wrap an tell block around the handler call.

```
tell application "Mail"
  my show_Dialog("this will work for sure")
end tell
```

or

```
tell application "Mail"
  show_Dialog("this will work for sure") of me
end tell
```

or

```
tell application "Mail"
   tell me
      show_Dialog("this will work for sure")
   end tell
end tell
```